# How to use images for check boxes using CSS or may be JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

It is obviously very simple question but I have never done such thing before. My designer want some thing like this for check boxes (it is on left side. Checked ones are grey and other white).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to use a span with background-image (empty box), hide a related checkbox, and assign a clickhandler to the the span (onclick: change checked attribute of the related hidden checkbox, change background image of the span accordingly).

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/X6nyd/) of that

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing i use jQuery UI. An example is here : http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

and some example code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#check" ).button();
    $( "#format" ).buttonset();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am not using "jQuery UI" in my site, for this small piece of visual effect do you think I should include jQuery UI Core and UI Widget to my javascripts?

Comment: I Would yes, jQuery UI also takes care of any cross browser problems with the checkboxes :)