# Changing a checked checkbox from a tick to a solid background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By default when you check a checkbox it will put a tick in the box. I'm trying to change that to a solid color weather it be a css background or an image upon check. http://bootply.com/71996

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    Content
</label>
```

I've searched and read a few answers on here but nothing conclusive and simple.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496581/how-to-use-images-for-check-boxes-using-css-or-may-be-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [your updated code](http://bootply.com/72014).

**HTML:**

```
<label class="checkbox">
<input value="" type="checkbox">
Content
</label>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  var $chk = $(this);
  var isChecked = $chk.prop('checked');
  if (isChecked) {
    $chk.parent().addClass("checked");
  }
  else {
    $chk.parent().removeClass("checked");
  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.checkbox { color:blue; }
.checkbox:before { content:""; background-color:blue; width:15px; height:18px; display:block; position:absolute; margin-left:-20px; }
.checkbox.checked { color:red; }
.checkbox.checked:before { background-color:red; }
```

Note:

The JavaScript can be simplified but I intentionally check at the value (and not use `.toggleClass()`) each time it changed.